# Automatically highlighting added rows in G-Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a entire sheet that I need to make adjustments to by adding new rows with values. I am manually using fill color to highlight what I have added. Could G-Sheets automatically highlight the new data I am inserting?  Here is an example below of what I am doing, I added row 3 in-between the preexisting data, so instead of manually highlighting the row I added I would like for it to automatically highlight. Is that possible?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP2e7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HighLight on edit if edit value is not blank

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const ns = ['Sheet0'];
  const idx = ns.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if(~idx && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('highlight');
    e.range.setBackground("#ffff00")
  }
}
```

Comment: Very concise answer